# Split item in nested list, move and copy

Tags: python, list, nested, copy, append

I have the following List made up of multiple nested Lists.

```
data_v1 = [
['Toronto', 'blue', 'Val1, Val2'],
['Amsterdam', 'red', 'Val1'],
['New York', 'white', 'Val1, Val2']
]
```

For every nested list that contains the comma in the third item, I would like to split that third item based off the the comma, and create two new nested lists for the number of values originally there. So the new list would look like this.

```
data_v2 = [
['Toronto', 'blue', 'Val1'],
['Toronto', 'blue', 'Val2'],
['Amsterdam', 'red', 'Val1'],
['New York', 'white', 'Val1'],
['New York', 'white', 'Val2']
]
```

Comment: `[val[:-1] + [v] for val in data_v1 for v in val[-1].split(', ')]`?

Comment: It did indeed! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Functionally equivalent to *Mechanic Pig*'s list comprehension:

```py
data_v1 = [
['Toronto', 'blue', 'Val1, Val2'],
['Amsterdam', 'red', 'Val1'],
['New York', 'white', 'Val1, Val2']
]

data_v2 = []
for sublist in data_v1:
    for value in sublist[2].split(", "):
        data_v2.append([*sublist[:2], value])

expected_data_v2 = [
['Toronto', 'blue', 'Val1'],
['Toronto', 'blue', 'Val2'],
['Amsterdam', 'red', 'Val1'],
['New York', 'white', 'Val1'],
['New York', 'white', 'Val2']
]

print(data_v2 == expected_data_v2)
```

Output:

```
True
```